# Meaning of 「制止に入る」

Tags: translation

The following phrase appears in the manga The Seven Deadly Sins' latest chapter, 328.

> 制{せい}止{し}に入{はい}った 
>   ザラトラス聖{せい}騎{き}士{し}長{ちょう}に 
>   まで重{じゅう}傷{しょう}を負{お}わせた！！

I cannot understand it properly. I couldn't find the definition of 「制止に入る」, only 「制止が入る」. The latter, as I understand it, means "to be stopped"; "to be restrained". However, I was told that the context suggests 「制止に入る」 has the exact opposite meaning, because the Great Holy Knight Zaratras was the one restraining somebody, and he suffered a lot for that.

I don't read the manga, so I can't be sure.

If 「制止に入る」 really means "to restrain", then would 「邪魔に入る」 mean "to interrupt"? Given that 「邪魔が入る」 means "to be interrupted".

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 制止に入る and 制止が入る could be said as the "opposite" in some sense, for the speaker of the sentence. That said, it is nothing like that the particles indicate voices or something, but due to construction.

制止 means "holding back from doing some action", and in this case, probably "intervention to stop a fight". 入る of course has tons of meanings generally translated like "[verb] in". The point is, が marks nominative (i.e. subject) while に marks destination, or purpose. Thus the two phrases actually come from different compositions:

- 制止が（X に）入る "the intervention cuts in (on X)" → *(X) is intervened*
- （X が）制止に入る "(X) cuts in for intervention" → *(X) intervenes*

And Japanese freely omit known agents where English tends to place pronouns, so that you might see only the portion you'll see.

> ザラトラス聖騎士長が制止に入った *Great Holy Knight Zaratras tried to intervene*
>
> → 制止に入ったザラトラス聖騎士長 *G.H.K Zaratras, who tried to intervene*

---

> *then would 「邪魔に入る」 mean "to interrupt"? Given that 「邪魔が入る」 means "to be interrupted".*

Yes, for the very same reason.

Comment: Can I actually use 「制止が入った」 on a relative cause? Like 「制止が入ったザラトラス聖騎士長」 "The Great Holy Knight Zaratras, who was held back". I know that you can say things like 「粋がわかる人」 even though 「人」 would be marked by the 「に」 particle, so I imagine it's the same for 「制止が入った」, but I'm not sure whether he or his action would be the object. Why is it that Zaratras only tried to intervene and not necessarily succeeded? Is it the verb 「入る」 that adds that nuance? In the structure 「ザラトラス聖騎士長が制止に入った」, how would I mark what he is trying to intervene in? Would only the particle 「は」 apply? Like 「喧嘩はザラトラス聖騎士長が制止に入った」

Comment: @E.Matsunaga Yes, 制止が入ったザラトラス聖騎士長 means what you mean; and yes, I intended that 入る somewhat stands for "try to" here; the most natural ways to mark the target of intervention are ～が **[A]の**制止に入った, where the event mostly comes in A, and ～が **[B]を**制止**しに**入った, where the event or person comes in B.

Comment: @E.Matsunaga Oh btw you can also say it more colloquially 止【と】めに入る (but not *止めが入る).